# Is IEntityWithChangeTracker compatible with WPF Binding?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4.1

Before getting into too much trouble. I want to know if the IEntityWithChangeTracker is compatible with WPF notification system to refresh the UI when properties are changed or do I need to hard code INotifyPropertyChanged pattern in my POCO classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `INotifyPropertyChanged` - `IEntityWithChangeTracker` has completely different purpose.

Comment: This sucks in the POCO approach. You have to define full properties in order to achieve this. I guess I'll be forced to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Thanks for your answer.